# Performance problem Loading Dataset inside a virtual

Tags: .net, performance, virtual

Host Configuration:

- HP EliteBook 8530w
- 4G Ram
- Win7 Ultimate 64Bit RC
- SQL Server 2005 64bit Developer Edition

Virtual:

- Windows Virtual PC
- 1G Ram allocated
- Integration Services installed
- Windows XP 64bit
- Up to date service packs and .Net framework through 3.5 SP1
- Sharing the Gigabit network adapter of the Host

I have a simple .Net console application which loads a dataset of approximately 37K rows.  Running the application on the host executes in approximately 4 seconds.  Running inside the virtual takes 729 seconds.  The size of the application grows to about 65Mb when the dataset is finished loading, no calculated columns or event handlers are attached.

[edit] I changed the virtual to use a loopback adapter to communicate with the host and performance is now on par with running on hardware.

Any ideas as to why it would going over the network adapter be almost 200x longer?  TraceRt shows that the connection is only one hop.

Thanks,
Shane Holder

Answer (score 0):

Default serialization of a DataTable/DataSet is pretty verbose. Check what's happening on the wire. You're probably getting some repetitive XML.

Comment: There shouldn't be any serialization on the wire.  No web services involved, and no transmission of the actual dataset itself, just creation and loading in the console application.